# If i have a nested map as a value to a multimap how can i insert values into the inner map?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, multimap

I am trying to implement a dictionary where i have an outer map (as a multimap) with the key being the word being searched and the value being the inner map, which will have several pairs itself with different values which all can map to the outer multimap key.

for example: the word **Distinct** has several meanings depending if its a noun, verb, adjective, or pronoun ==> ***noun***- A keyword in this program
**adverb**- *Uniquely. Written "distinctly"* etc.

I am thinking of mapping the word **Distinct** as the *key* to the outer multimap and mapping the part of speech as the key to the inner map with the definitions as the inner map's values.

so far i declared the multimap as this:

```
typedef map<string, string> valMap;

multimap<string,valMap> myMultMap;
```

and i have tried adding values by using *insert()* like this:

```
myMultMap.insert("Diction", valMap.insert(pair<string,string>("fun", "first Value"));
```

I am just learning maps and still unsure as to the inner working of iterators in the maps. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Or maybe consider using a `map<pair<string, string>, string> instead. That way, you have a combined key instead of nested maps. It make some operations easier and other harder. It really depends on how the data is used. In production code, I would probably hide those details inside a class (or two)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first create the variable you need to insert:

```
valMap tmp;
tmp.insert(make_pair("fun", "first Value"));
```

Then insert this `tmp` into the main map:

```
myMultMap.insert(make_pair("Diction", move(tmp)));
```

Comment: wow it worked thanks so much! if i didnt use typedef map<string, string> valMap; but instead just declared the valMap how would i be able to accomplish the same? or is it i would have to use typedef to do it? so asking for clarity. and im guessing to access it i would need to iterate the inner map then the outer in a loop?

Comment: Obviously, without the typedef, you would wrote `map<string, string> tmp` and the remaining of the code won't change.

Comment: I'm just using the typedef because it's easy and it makes sure that it's the same type that we put inside the `multimap`.

Answer (score 1):

First, create the inner map and store it into a variable. Then use `insert` to add it into the outer map.

Comment: do you mean something like ' myMultMap.insert(pair<string,map<string, string>>("Distinct", _not sure how to insert here_));'? thank you for your quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

`multimap::insert` returns an iterator to the stored entry. You can use this iterator to insert items into inserted map without creating any temporary variables. It is also a good idea to use `emplace` forwarding arguments directly to entry constructor instead of `insert` to avoid creation of temporaries:

```
using t_Map = ::std::map<::std::string, ::std::string>;
using t_Multimap = ::std::multimap<::std::string, t_Map>;
t_Multimap multimap{};
auto const p_entry
{
    multimap.emplace
    (
        ::std::piecewise_construct
    ,   ::std::forward_as_tuple("Diction")
    ,   ::std::forward_as_tuple()
    )
};
auto & map{p_entry->second};
map.emplace
(
    ::std::piecewise_construct
,   ::std::forward_as_tuple("fun")
,   ::std::forward_as_tuple("first Value")
);
```